# Deluge does not work properly

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

My Deluge torrent client does not starts downloading or uploading files. Always says 0.0 kb/s.

Comment: Does transmission work as a comparison? Trying to get an idea of BitTorrent is working on your network in general.

Comment: I used to use uTorrent with the same IPS. Worked well on Win10.  I am using `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Deluge 1.3.13`. Im  trying to use Deluge because had very good recommendation among Uubuntu community. I will try how uTorrent works on Ubuntu. Are there any Canonical packages for it?

Comment: Deluge is great, but sadly the way it's packaged in Ubuntu is not great. I was curious if transmission (the built in BitTorrent client) works before I got into the details of the package problems with Deluge.

Comment: Deluge is provided as many packages because they break it up into "server" and GUI packages. I can't remember what packages are needed to install it such that it "just works" for a desktop user. A basic installation will do "thin mode" nonsense and honestly even after you avoid that by installing libtorrent that it's going to want to hook up to a server that runs on the same system. It's dumb as rocks for a basic GUI user.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the torrents are not paused, and that you don't have speed limits or alternate speed limits enabled?

Comment: I have checked all things that you are pointing out.  Everything was OK. Now I realised it just need a lot of time to start. It is working now. But every time I turn it on, it takes about 1-2 minutes to start all operations. It is not correlated to VPN settings. It does not matter if VPN is turned on or turned off, always there is a lag on downlaoding, uploading, trackers update etc.